# horizontal ProgressBar outofmemory error?

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-progressbar

I'm having OutOfMemoryError when I write:

```
progressBar[j] = new ProgressBar(context, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);
```

but when I replace it with:

```
progressBar[j] = new ProgressBar(context, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge);
```

there are no errors.
Why is that so?
Besides, the stack trace points here.
btw, I'm having multiple ProgressBar, and the succeeding ProgressBar are created at runtime.
The number of ProgressBar depends on the number of images in the database.
Some progressbar and images are appended on the activity by clicking a button, "See More".
I'm also using asynctask in downloading the images.

Comment: whats the progressDrawable?

Comment: don't focus on that line. It is not the real cause.

Comment: The OutOfMemory error comes from a diffrent place. Maybe the resources for the horizontal progressBar are bigger and that fills the memory ,  but the error comes from a diffent place. To solve OOM errors i advice you to check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk)

Comment: your `OutOfMemory` comes from the images you're holding on memory, not from the ProgressBar

Comment: i'm saving all the images on the sd card and loading them on the imageview onPostExecute of the asynctask of the download. I also suspected it. @blackbelt then what is the real cause?

Comment: It is hard to answer. Are you aware that a bitmap needs w*h*4 bytes to be stored in *RAM*?

Comment: no, but am i storing it to RAM when I saving it to sd card first and loading the image after? I'm setting the inputstream of the download to point to the fileoutputstream of the file in sd card. btw, i make the progressbar overlap with the imageview so that when i setVisibility(View.gone) the progressbar would be covered by the image